# data not showing in first click in react.js

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
const App = () => {

    const [txt,setTxt] = useState("")
    const [num,setNum]= useState(0);
    const [data, setData]=useState([]);
 
    const Clicked = ()=>{
        const obj={
            id: data.length === 0 ? 1 : data[data.length-1].id +1,
            str:txt,
            tot:num,
        }
        setData([...data,obj])
        console.log(data)
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <div className='input-section'>
            <h4>input your data here</h4>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setTxt(e)}/>
            <h4>it is for number</h4>
            <input type="number" onChange={(e)=>setNum(e)}/><br />
            <br />
            <button onClick={Clicked}>Send the data</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

export default App

once the data are filled and after clicking the button why i'm getting an empty array. If i have filled the input section then i should get that data after clicking it but i wont work. It works but i have to double click it why is that. Suggest me solution for this please.